# Stackoverflow pt e eng

Tags: suporte

Olá é o seguinte uma pergunta minha foi fechada por estar fora do escopo no Stackoverflow pt mas encontrei uma pergunta praticamente a mesma coisa no Stackoverflow ing mas não esta fora do escopo qual é a diferença?
[PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149501/skype-bot-detecta-quando-receber-mensagem)
[ING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309808/skype-bot-c-sharp-not-running-correctly)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Com a edição da resposta ela pode ser útil e com a resposta a pergunta pode ser reaberta. Do jeito que estava ficou sem uma solução real. A solução seria "leia um site externo" e isso não funciona aqui. Do jeito que estava a pergunta não ajudaria mais ninguém e o opção de não pode ser reproduzida é o mais próximo que se tem para fechar para algo muito específico.

Note que a pergunta no SO está bem negativada e provavelmente não foi fechada por ter passado desapercebida. A pergunta está bem ruim lá e aqui também não estava ajudando ninguém.

Quando coloca uma resposta (o que foi feito) que pode salvar a pergunta sinalize para um moderador ver o que pode ser feito.

Answer (score 9):

Por favor não leve a mal, tudo que irei dizer é para lhe orientar. A pergunta tem dois problemas

1. Não tem o código completo e você fala de um suposto tutorial que nem sabemos o que é, fora que não sabemos como são as classes `ChatMessage` e `TChatMessageStatus`, isto torna a pergunta suscetível a ser fechada como:

   > não está clara o suficiente
2. A sua própria resposta que foi um erro seu ao seguir o tutorial, fora que você fala de DLLs (na verdade são libs, a dll contem as libs, mas isso é outra historia), isto torna a pergunta suscetível a ser fechada como:

   > Fora do escopo > Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação.

A pergunta não estava clara, ou seja, ninguém poderia responde-la, seria impossível, só você mesmo poderia responder. Não adianta esperar que as pessoas "adivinhem" como são as classes e qual tutorial você usou, você deve fornecer um exemplo do problema que as pessoas possam executar com facilidade.

Na verdade esse é o maior erro da maioria das pessoas, elas esperam que os outros entendam seus problemas sem dar o código de uma maneira que possa ser executado, tem muito usuário com excesso de boa vontade que até tentam ajudar, mas o resultado muitas vezes não agrada a quem pergunta.

### O que é um exemplo que pode ser executado

É uma versão simplificada ou inteira do seu código, para você facilitar o lado de quem vai tentar responder a pergunta deve ter:

- Código que basta copiar apenas e colar, deve conter os includes e etc
- O código deve ser uma versão simplificada do seu se possível
- Se o teu código usa libs de terceiros deve informar o link para que a pessoa possa obter tais libs

Deve-se sempre tentar seguir as orientações do Help, para este caso, principalmente estas duas:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

A pergunta no SOen não foi fechada por provavelmente apenas alguns usuários que não tem poder de fechamento terem notado ela, foi alguma falta de atenção apenas, como dito pelo @bigown, mas note pelos downvotes que o pessoal no SOen não gostou dela por algum motivo, não é um problema com código, mas sim de como a pergunta foi feita (provavelmente, cada um vota pelo motivo que quiser).

Então eu acho que a pergunta deve continuar fechada, no caso já votei por fechar.

Comment: Eu corcordo. Vamos ver como se desenvolve.

Comment: *" o maior erro da maioria das pessoas, elas esperam que os outros entendam seus problemas sem dar o código de uma maneira que possa ser executado"* - sem duvida! E alguns você pede e ainda acham ruim.